# Prove that if $A$ is invertible then $AA^\top$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove that if $A$ is a square invertible matrix then $AA^\top$ ($A$ multiply $A$ transpose) is positive definite.

I tried to prove that all the eigenvalues are positive.
I know that $AA^\top$ is symmetric, and its **determinant is positive**, and **trace is positive**.

Therefore:
product of **eigenvalues is positive** , and **sum of eigenvalues is positive**.

In addition $0$ is not an eigenvalue. That's what I know so far but I still cannot conclude that every eigenvalue for itself is positive. What have I missed? Thanks!

Comment: It's easier to check the definition directly. $B$ is positive definite if and only if $\langle x, Bx\rangle > 0$ for all $x\neq 0$.

Comment: $\langle X, A A^t x\rangle = \langle A^t x, A^tx\rangle \geq 0$ and it equals zero iff $A^t x=0$ which is iff $x=0$.

Comment: This question and its semi-definite variant seem to appear here at least once a week.

Answer (score 4):

If you set $B=A^T$ and $C=AA^T=B^TB$, then it should be easier: the definition of positive definite is that
$$
x^TCx>0
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\ne0$.

Since
$$
x^TCx=x^TB^TBx=(Bx)^T(Bx)
$$
you can set $y=Bx$; then you know that $y^Ty>0$ if $y\ne0$; can $y$ be zero when $x\ne0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be a non-zero vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$ (here $x$ is a row vector). Since $A$ is invertible, $xA$ is also non-zero. Then
$$
  0 < \langle xA,xA \rangle = xA(xA)^\top = x AA^\top x^\top = x (AA^\top) x^\top.
$$
The latter implies that $AA^\top$ is positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $A$ is a real matrix (otherwise, the statement is not true).

Prove positive definiteness by definition:

$B$ is positive definite if $\langle x,Bx\rangle> 0$ for all $x\neq 0$. For $B=BB^T$, you have $$\langle x, BB^T x\rangle.$$

Now, prove that this is $\geq 0$ by taking into account that $\langle x, Ax\rangle = \langle A^T x, x\rangle$ for any matrix $A$.

Comment: I don't know this definition. I know that symmetric bi-linear form f is positive definite if f(u,u) > 0 . How can I derive your definition from it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix has my definition of positive definiteness.

Comment: I see the definition that z^tMz is positive for every nonzero z vector, but how is it connected to inner product

Comment: @CnR $z^TMz = \langle z, Mz\rangle$

Comment: using the standard inner product?

Comment: @CnR indeed. It's easy to see that $x^Ty=\langle x,y\rangle$ for $x,y\in \mathbb R^n$